# How do you pronounce the name "Kahlan"?

Tags: names, pronunciation, the-sword-of-truth

What is the proper pronunciation of the name? I found a lot of different versions on fan forums, and also in the real world. Yes, people name their daughters after Kahlan Amnell!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The author pronounces it (depending on his mood) as Kay-linn or Kay-lenn.

**Kay-lenn**

**Kay-Linn** (in [this interview](https://soundcloud.com/freetalklive/ftl2007-01-24#t=4:10) he corrects the interviewer and explicitly confirms the pronunciation.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1:**
In "Legend Of The Seeker", it is pronounced as 'Kay-lin'

**Answer 2:**
According to an old interview with Terry Goodkind (sadly disappeared from the site after redesign), it is pronounced as 'Kay-lin'.

So the correct version is 'Kay-lin'

Comment: Thank you for your info.  Unfortunately, my brain will refuse to ever use an 'a' as an i sound, and even if I change it to a schwa (as I suspect is intended) it feels terribly dumb, so I will continue to use my own headcannon pronunciation (KAH-lahn).

Comment: Can you offer any evidence?

Comment: There seems to be this habit in sci-fi and fantasy to pronounce 'ah' as a hard 'ay' sound - in Star Trek, for example, Kahless was pronounced "Kay-less", "K'Eyleyr" was pronounced "Kay-lair", and, of course, "Kahlan" pronounced as "Kay-lin". I reject this pronunciation, of course, and substitute my own.